# SSAS MDX calculation

Tags: ssas, mdx

I need a calculated measure(SSAS MD) to calculate the percentage of count values.

I have tried below expression but I did not get the desired output.Let me know if I missing anything and I want to calculate the percentage of the age for the group by the car total:

```
    ( [DimCar].[Car], [DimAge].[Age], [Measure].[Count])/ 
sum([DimCar].[Car].[All].children), ([DimAge].[Age].[All], [Meaures].[Count])}*100
```

Below are the sample date values in cube:

```html
Car     Age   Count
-----  -----  -----
Benz     1      2
Camry           37
Honda    1      18
Honda    6      10

Expected output:


Car    Age    Count Percent  TotalCount 
----- -----  ----- ------ ---------- 
Benz   1       2   100%       2   
Camry         37   100%       37    
Honda  1      18   64.28%     28    
Honda  6      10   35.71%     28
```

Forumula to calculate percentage:

```
18/28*100 =64.28% 
10/28*100 =35.71%   

Honda  1  18   64.28%  28    
Honda  6  10   35.71%  28
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I need the calculation expression for the desired output

Comment: I have tried below expression but i did not get the desired output.Let me know if i missing anything and i want to calculate the percentage of the age for the group by the car total..

      (
[DimCar].[Car],
[DimAge].[Age],
[Measure].[Count])/
sum([DimCar].[Car].[All].children),
([DimAge].[Age].[All],
[Meaures].[Count])}*100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
with Member  [Measures].[Total Sales Count] 
as iif (isempty([Measures].[Sales]),NUll, sum([Model].[Modelname].[All].children ,[Measures].[Sales]))

Member [Measures].[Total Sales%]
as ([Measures].[Sales]/[Measures].[Total Sales Count]),FORMAT_STRING = "Percent"

select {[Measures].[Sales],[Measures].[Total Sales Count],[Measures].[Total Sales%]
}on 0
,non empty{[Car].[Carname].[Carname]*[Model].[Modelname].[Modelname]} on 1
from [Cube]
```

```html
Output :

Car     Model     Sales  Total Sales Count  Total Sales%
Benz  New Model   2     2                   100.00%
Camry  Old Model  37     37                 100.00%
Honda  New Model  18     28                  64.29%
Honda  Top Model  10     28                  35.71%
```

Instead of "Age" attribute I have added "Model" dimension.
Below code get exact output which is expected.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZWiT.png)

Comment: Welcome here Pinku & thanks for the answer! Please try to use code format to comment code, and link images only of results that are not text-based - it makes your comment much more useful and easier to read.

Comment: I have another question related but not sure if i can ask here or create a new question..

Comment: I want MDX(Query) expression for namedset or calculated measures for below tsql  

Tsql:
When [product].[Name] in (car1,car2,car3,car4,car5) Then
     [Measure].[Factcount] =0
     ELSE [Measure].[Factcount] =0

I tried below MDX 

IIF
({[product].[Name].&[car1],[product].[Name].&[car2],
[product].[Name].&[car3],[product].[Name].&[car4],
[product].[Name].&[car5]},[Measure].[Factcount] =0,[Measure].[Factcount] =1)

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that for a particular car example honda, you want to divide by the total honda's irrespective of their Age. In this case 28. So for Age:six  honda you use 10/28. Where as for Benz, since all Benz are Age: 1 you use 2.
Use the following code

```
 Round(
(
    ( [DimCar].[Car].currentmember, [DimAge].[Age].currentmember, [Measure].[Count])
    / 
    ([DimCar].[Car].currentmember,root([DimAge]),[Measure].[Count])
    )*100
,2)
```

Below is a similar example on adventure works

```
with member 
measures.t as 
(
( [Product].[Category].currentmember, [Delivery Date].[Calendar Year].currentmember, [Measures].[Internet Order Quantity])
/ 
([Product].[Category].currentmember,root([Delivery Date]),[Measures].[Internet Order Quantity])
)*100
select {[Measures].[Internet Order Quantity],measures.t} 
on columns ,

non empty
([Product].[Category].[Category],[Delivery Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year])
on rows 
from [Adventure Works]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked and it produces the expected output with the percentages...I want to limit the percentage output decimals in the output..

Comment: ex:90.6777777% to 90.67%

Comment: @Kusu you are welcome, edited the answer to address rounding. You might consider marking it as answer.